# Query the Firestore offline data first even if the app is online

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve/query the Firestore offline data first even if the app is online like how we were doing in realtime db of Firebase?

Can anyone please help me with this issue for Android?

Thanks,

Satish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force the retrieval of the data from the cache while you're connected to the server. Firestore is desinged to retrieve data from the chache only when the device is permanently offline or while your application temporarily loses its network connection and unfortunately you cannot change this behaviour.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the reply but can you help me with some workaround for such scenarios or should you recommend implementing a local database and disable the offline persistence of Firestore and later sync the database with cloud firestore.

Comment: I don't know the functionality of your app, but according to your needs you can do what you said.

Comment: That's ok, but why do you want to get the data from the cache while you are online?

Comment: My requirement is pretty straight forward, I have an activity which holds 3 different fragments and the first fragment is responsible for inflating the recycler view which displays a list of feed items coming from firestore directly and binding to the adapter. So when you first lunch the app it should load the offline content first rather than directly fetching from network which causes a bit of delay and once the fresh feeds are downloaded it shoukd show a "new feeds" popup on top and only if user clicks on that popup it should show the new feeds. eg. linkedIn app

Comment: You can display a `ProgressBar` while downloading data, for a better user experience. But if that delay is so big, then go ahead with your solution.

Comment: well lets say we have 10 users currenly using the app, and each one is scrolling through the feeds, and suddenly one/more user(s) posted a new feed. Then following the above solution of displaying a progress bar can cause a bad user experience for the other active users as we are interrupting their work flow and forcefully popping up the pregressbar. Because firestore listener will be called as soon as the data  gets updated/added/deleted in the backend. What you think Alex? Can we use some conditional logic over here?

Comment: I advised you to use a `ProgressBar` **only** when you are getting the data for the first time. In the other situation there is no need to do something.

Comment: @AlexMamo I agree with you and I think that firebase team should provide that option by default, to query local data first before online, to provide a faster user experience